# Is it possible to achieve same url routing architecture in next JS?

Tags: next.js, routes

I have 2 path in my next js app which are colliding. first one is **abc.com/car/mahindra/thar** , second one is **abc.com/car/suv/5-6-lakhs**. In first url mahindra is manufacturer name and in second one suv is body type so both manufacturer can be differ it's not a static value like it can be abc.com/car/maruti/swift or abc.com/sedan/7-8lakhs.

do we have any possible way to achieve this task ?

I want to know can we achieve same level routing or any other way i can handle this conflict of routs?

Comment: If you have a list of all the possible values, you should be able to write routing code that does the right thing.  Can you combine it into a single route handler?

Comment: Maybe you could use middleware to check if the route info is a car type or manufacturer and then send the user to the route with necessary info. Another way of doing it would be to separete the routes adding manufacturer and cartType to the url.